# "[Errno 13] Permission denied" on PIL Image.open if path and filename are not given in a raw string

Tags: python, exception, python-imaging-library, rawstring

I am dealing with an issue on the `Image.open()` function from `PIL` in Python.

I try to open an image from a path / folder saved on a string:

```
path_and_filename = "c:\tmp\test.jpeg"

image = Image.open(path_and_filename)
```

Then I get the error:

```
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\tmp\\test.jpeg'
```

If I define the path and filename as a raw string, it works:

```
path_and_filename = r"c:\tmp\test.jpeg"

image = Image.open(path_and_filename)
```

The error message regarding "permission" makes no sense, since it works on the same file if it is definied as a raw string.

Do you see any solution or recommendetation for this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The "permission" issue was solved:

The files were copied into a hotfolder monitored by watchdog and the watchdog started the `Image.open()` function.

The files were sometimes not completelly copied into the folder and the function was already trying to open it. That is why I got the "permission" error message.

After setting a delay `time.sleep()` before calling the open function, it was possible to call it.

Note: the script was working on the raw variable since I set an already copied file name on it.

Answer (score -1):

Put it in the same file path that all your .py files are and than you don’t need the path you just call the file name

```
   Image = image.open(‘test.jpg’)
```

Comment: That's quite the restriction, though.